# Aws wordpress EC2 with 503 service unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

This is my first time using wordpress on EC2 (I have 0 knowledge about it. I just follow youtube tutorial...). It was fine when I created in July until last week. I ran into 503 error

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

and saw articles saying the instance load balancer needs to set to a target group(I follow AWS documentation but it shows unused). Can anyone help me? My site is been down for one week already :( Thank you.

Edit:
I ssh into the instance and saw my port 80 and 443 was block. So I rerun it make it active and my site is back again. For the targets I had 301 error code and I change the health checks success codes to 301 and its now healthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target group is not receiving traffic from the load balancer it seems.

Remove the instance from the load balancer. Then configure the load balancer to send traffic to the target group.

If you don't see target group option in your load balancer, you must be using a classic load balancer. You can instead use an application load balancer.

this is what you can do:

- Elastic load balancer:

remove the instance from the ELB, because you don't want to use the elastic load balancer, we will create an application load balancer

- Target Group

Ensure you have healthy instances. If you don't have healthy instances, check your health check. is your heath check logic seems correct. is it `http`, and port `80`, and the health check path is `/` ? does the path return `200 OK` response.

- Application load balancer

When you create an application load balancer, first you will select the subnets that you want to use, after that it will let you choose an existing target group. again choose the correct protocol, port options.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204822/discussion-on-answer-by-arun-k-aws-wordpress-ec2-with-503-service-unavailable).

Comment: have you fixed this, do you still need help.

Comment: Hi, I have not. I'm trying to ssh into the instance but it seems like there's some problem with my key. It said its a public key not private key.

Comment: worse case should i just remove the instance and reset the Wordpress? I have the whole wordpress file backup. (.wpress file)

Comment: I see the system log has some lines saying 
[  141.448756] bitnami[1077]: /opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
[  146.680799] bitnami[1077]: /opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm could not be started
[  151.888775] bitnami[1077]: Syntax OK
[  152.164295] bitnami[1077]: /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
[  152.307787] bitnami[1077]: write /var/lib/gonit/state: no space left on device
[  152.468688] bitnami[1077]: Unable to initialize installer.

is the spacing causing my wordpress not running at all?

Comment: your errors shows that you have `/opt/bitnami` directories. i think you should restart all the services without `sudo` command.so `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start` . before that, to check hard disk space , try the command `df -h`

Comment: it is entirely possible that the services are not starting because of not enough space.  you could also increase the volume size.

Comment: Due to my reputation is too low I can't move the discussion to chat. anyway, I finally being able to ssh in and fix it. (the spacing part was because I back up the wordpress a lot of time so it ran out of space. I removed most of it already). but now only the ip address is working. I see my hosted zones still the same only updated record A for the value after I change ELB to ALB. my domain is not connect to the IP :(

Comment: It is actually working! I guess i just need to wait for a few minutes to update. So now everything is fine as before!!!! however, my target group still said unhealthy even thought the site is working fine and the instance check is good.

Comment: One says you can use `/favico.ico` for health check. Can you try to access `http://IP/favico.ico` before configure it for health check

Comment: omg just check again the site now is saying 502 bad getaway... it was running fine yesterday

Comment: It's weird. I just check the site again and for some reason the port 80 and 443 was block again (I return apace yesterday to reopen port 80 and 443 and the site was showing). Do you know if that has anything to do with the target group stuff? something is keep turning the port off.

Comment: what happens when you access `http://IP/favico.ico`, if its working, then the issue is, target group finds the instance unhealthy

Comment: Now its showing unhealthy and code 301. I found https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/dhu6nd/alb_failing_health_checks_301/ saying to just add accept 301 but I'm not sure how to do that. Can I do that through AWS console or I have to go through the terminal again? Thank you.

Comment: Go-to the target group health check, change the status code to 301

Comment: Yesss!! It's healthy now. Thank you so much @Arun K. can I at least buy you a coffee?

Comment: Glad to help you, lol :) I love coffee :) though. but upvote is enough.

Comment: Wish you have a fantastic new year in the new decade ;)